# Microsoft Graph API - app in powershell - forbidden response

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to make a Microsoft Graph API call using powershell 5.1. I have Registred the app. I use the AppID and secret to obtain an Authorization Bearer token. I then construct my API request.  The security/events endpoint only returns a Forbidden response.

[API Permissions Granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ3hN.png)

My script to make the call looks like this:

```
# Define AppId, secret and scope, your tenant name and endpoint URL
$AppId = [myAPPID]
$AppSecret = [myAPPSecret]
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$TenantName = "[mytenant].onmicrosoft.com"

$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Add System.Web for urlencode
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$Body = @{
        client_id = $AppId
        client_secret = $AppSecret
        scope = $Scope
        grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}

# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Method = 'POST'
    # Create string by joining bodylist with '&'
    Body = $Body
    Uri = $Url
}

$Request = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat

$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/events"

$SecurityAlertsRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
```

Just looking to see If I have missed something obvious. Is there any other reason this would response with Forbidden for this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have granted delegated permissions to the app.
Those only apply when there is a user signed in to your app and you acquire an access token to act on their behalf.

You need to grant *application permissions* to your app in Azure AD.